# .click() highlighting but not moving element selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on a webpage element using selenium in python. The element is this:

```
<span>Exchange NC</span>
```

I have tried the following:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.<METHODS>((By.XPATH, 'normal_xpath'))).click()
```

where I have used these methods:

```
element_to_be_clickable
visibility_of_element_located
presence_of_element_located
```

And I have also used this xpath which I created, in addition to the xpath I copied from inspection:

```
'//span[.="Exchange NC"]'
```

I also tried selecting the higher level DIV, not the span.

The result in every case is that most of the time the element becomes highlighted on the webpage as if I am hovering over it. But the item is not truly clicked - I confirm this because when clicked it should move to another portion of the page. Only sometimes does it click. But there is no error.

I have also tried looping the .click() attempt 5 times. It will successfully click some portion of the time.

Any ideas on what is happening here?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more of your html code for the element?

Comment: Can you try clicking it twice. Like `element.click()` and again  `element.click()` And if you could share the page link too.

Comment: Clicking twice seems to be a stable solution, thank you! I should have thought of that, I have done that before but it's been a while and it's so strange. Do you know why that is necessary? I can't share the link - it's an internal company url.

Comment: Could you try to click it via javascript?  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", yourElement);